# What are the different awards I can get and how do I get them?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

After a versus game, the players are awarded with awards based on things that happened during the game. What are all the different awards that you can get? How do I get each of them?

Comment: 15 new awards were added in an update, bringing the total to 70. [There is a full list on the Towerfall Wiki](http://towerfall.wikidot.com/awards).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Most Lethal** - Dispatched the most archers.

**Bubble Breaker Award** - Destroyed the most shields.

**Quick Draw Award** - Be efficient. (don't hold the shoot button to aim)

**Most Devious** - Exploiting screen wrap.

**Most Vindictive** - Kills from beyond the grave.

**Greediest** - Swiped the most treasure.

**Longest Innings** - Survived the longest.

**Late To The Party Award** - Mostly Harmless. (only got the last kill in a round)

**Most Prepared** - Always ready for a fight!

**Least Prepared** - Gathered the least arrows.

**Most Trigger-Happy** - Shot the most arrows. Settle down!

**Worst Accounting** - Shooting with an empty quiver.

**Who Needs Arrows?** - For stomping archers to death.

**Marksmanship Award** - Best shot to kill ratio.

**Longest Shot** - Trick shot!

**Pickpocket Award** - Stole the most arrows.

**Most Regal** - Wore the crown the most.

**Regicide Award** - Assassinated the most queens and kings.

**Fetal Position Award** - Ducking the most.

**Cannonball Award** - Hold down to fall fast.

**Koala Award** - Clinging to ledges the most.

**Koala Hunter Award** - Killed those koalas.

**Most Evasive** - Dodged the most.

**Most Zen** - Caught the most arrows.

**Least Composed** - Dying during your dodge cool down.

**Artless Dodger Award** - Dodged a lot but never caught an arrow.

**Most Twitchy** - Barely catching arrows.

**Super Booper** - Crafty dodger. (get a kill while dodging)

**Most Takebacks** - Caught your own arrows.

**Turncloak Award** - Betrayed your teammates.

**Damage Control Award** - Crisis averted. (not sure, probably for killing someone who has a lot of dangerous arrows)

**Most Reckless** - Accident-prone. (dying on stage traps)

**Most Compressed** - Crushed by moving platforms :(

**Most Fashionable** - Retrieved your hat. Style points!

**Usurper Award** - For putting on other archers' crowns.

**William Tell Award** - Shot the hats off your enemies' heads.

**Bottle Rocket Award** - Adept at surviving explosions.

**Double Kill** - Two kills from one shot.

**Triple Kill** - Three kills from one shot.

**Cause And Effect Award** - Consequences.

**Bank Shot Award** - Best laser bounce kill.

**Green Thumb Award** - Call the Brambulance.

**X-Ray Vision Award** - Most Conductive.

**Right Angle Award** - Get a kill with a bolt arrow at 90 degrees.

**From The Grave Award** - Get a kill after dying.

**Eagle Eye Award** - Extreme accuracy.

**Vendetta Award** - Bullied a specific archer.

**Most Thorough** - Swept the most rounds.

**Comeback King** - won the match by just living (male characters)

**Comeback Queen** - won a match by just living (female characters)

**Comeback Kid** - won a match by just living (prancing puppet)

**Steak In Mouth Award** - reach the point limit but die in some way such that the match no longer ends.

**Consolation Prize** - Well, at least you showed up. (you didn't get any other awards)

**Overachiever Award** - finish with 2 kills more than the required kill limit.

**Ironman Award** - Didn't die at all.

Comment: @Seiyria Could you put explicit explanations for these awards?  I think the problem right now is that it looks like a copy and paste job.  I mean consider "Consolation Prize - Well, at least you showed up." Does that mean that you get it just for playing or what?  Also, the formatting leaves a lot to be desired, can you maybe bolden the award?

Comment: @spugsley Feel free to accept it if you feel it answers the question adequately.

Comment: [There is a list on GameRevolution](http://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/65353-towerfall-ascension-awards-list) which has more detailed descriptions for some of the awards. Would you be ok if I updated the descriptions and linked to the article, or should I post as a separate answer.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro given that there's already this list I think an edit would be more appropriate, since a new answer wouldn't be adding anything "new" in that sense.

Comment: It seems the Dark Word DLC added a few awards. The ingame archive now lists a total of 70 awards.

Answer (score 1):

The Steak in Mouth award is given to a player who was about to win, but then died before the final point could be awarded, followed by that player *losing* the match instead. Hence the award image of a King being shot with arrows.

The Cause and Effect award is for players who fire a laser arrow, but have that laser arrow ricochet back onto them, killing them.

Answer (score -1):

Someone over on Steam compiled [a slightly more complete list](http://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=242808826). Here are the important differences from the list above:

Quick Draw Award - Didn't hold the Shoot button to aim.

Late To The Party Award - Only got the last kill in a round.

Mostly Harmless - In over your head.

Artless Dodger Award - Dodged a lot, but never caught an arrow.

Super Booper - Stomped someone while dodging horizontally.

Damage Control Award - Caught an arrow fired at them by a teammate in TDM.

X-Ray Vision Award - Most drill arrow kills.

Most Conductive - Electrocuted an opponent. [Catch a bolt arrow to electrocute enemies near you]

Right Angle Award - Most bolt arrow kills.

From The Grave Award - Got a kill as a ghost. [Use the "Return as Ghost" variant, and touch a living player]

Comeback King/Queen/Kid - Won the match after hanging behind. [The "Kid" one is exclusive to the Prancing Puppet, all others are based on the archer's gender]

Steak In Mouth Award - Reached the point limit, lost the point by suicide [or any other way to lose a point], and then lost the match.

Overachiever Award - Finished with at least 2 points more than required by the point limit.

Comment: Please summarize the information here.  That way, if ever the website goes down, your answer is still useful.  Besides, it saves people a click.

Comment: Done, but I recommend clicking the link anyway. That list is being updated and corrected regularly, meaning it's likely to be the best source online. (At least, until TowerFall gets a proper wiki.)

Comment: This really just should have been an edit to my post above.