# What use is crouching?

Tags: towerfall-ascension

In *TowerFall*, the player can crouch by pressing down. This move doesn't seem all that useful; it only reduces your size by a bit, plus the arrows seek, and you can't move when crouching.

Are there situations where crouching is useful? Are there any special effects or techniques associated with crouching? Or is it just a [joke move](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FakeSpecialAttack)?

Comment: I have dodged arrows before when crouching.  Not often *(and not entirely intentional)*, but it's super-funny on the replays when it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrows don't always seek - you can turn that off with a variant. That said, even with seeking, sometimes the arrow takes a very sharp turn and will still miss you in some cases.

You are more likely to lose your hat if you duck while being shot.

Additionally, crouching allows you to retrieve your hat (if it was shot off), and it will also allow you to steal another players crown (provided you're not wearing one).

Crouching leads to [several of the awards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160033/what-are-the-different-awards-i-can-get-and-how-do-i-get-them/160130#160130) -- the most common one is the Fetal Position Award.

Crouching in the dark will hide you (provided you don't have Stealth Archers turned on), since you normally emit a small amount of light.

It is also necessary when doing [hyper jumping](http://towerfall.tumblr.com/post/101753964326/hyper-jumping-primer) (duck, then dodge in a bottom left or bottom right area, and jump -- you fly very far while doing this).